# How to send PNG image using Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, paperclip

I'm trying to send a Paperclip-uploaded image to an API.

How do I encode it?

Right now I'm using `attachment.queued_for_write[:original].read` to get the actual file contents of that PNG, and trying to send that in the body of my request. But the server isn't having it.

When I post the request via Postman, it works fine. How does Postman encode this? Unfortunately, trying to generate the Ruby code from Postman doesn't work, it just shows the file as `[Object object]` in the body of the request.

Comment: That depends third party API is expecting your files. See the docs for the API. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Launch Wireshark. Compare the POST request from Postman with the POST request from Net::HTTP.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30827339/5006469) may help you.

Comment: @Uzbekjon My question is, how does Postman encode this? This is a rinky dink API whose creator doesn't know the answer to the question. But it works with Postman, hence my question.

Comment: Which postman gem are you referring to? I've just looked through the this [postman's code](https://github.com/moomerman/postman) and even though the readme says it does webhook calls, it is not.

Comment: @Uzbekjon I'm actually talking about the Postman application, not a ruby gem. It lets you construct requests easily. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: This one: https://www.getpostman.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Postman docs say](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests) it is using standard form post. A [quick search](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html) resulted in this code:

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

# Token used to terminate the file in the post body. Make sure it is not
# present in the file you're uploading.
# You might want to use `SecureRandom` class to generate this random strings
BOUNDARY = "AaB03x"

uri = URI.parse("http://something.com/uploads")
file = "/path/to/your/testfile.txt"

post_body = []
post_body << "--#{BOUNDARY}\r\n"
post_body << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='datafile'; filename='#{File.basename(file)}'\r\n"
post_body << "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
post_body << "\r\n"
post_body << File.read(file)
post_body << "\r\n--#{BOUNDARY}--\r\n"

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.body = post_body.join
request["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data, boundary=#{BOUNDARY}"

http.request(request)
```

Comment: Here is a more elaborate solution:  https://coderwall.com/p/c-mu-a/http-posts-in-ruby